# Salesforce Marketing Cloud download API Biggest Table

Tags: marketing-cloud, api, soap, java

I'm trying download, for Soap calls, tables of Salesforce Marketing Cloud with 1 million or more rows but the process is very slowly.

For each download I can only get 2.500 records, ok.

I have used ETDataExtension / ETResponse / ETConfiguration

645.000 record in 1h30s

Do you know wich is the better solution for download big tables with Java? Maybe using other libraries?

I want download this data for make a parquet file.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the use case there are 2 options.

1. Have an automation running in Automation Studio with a Data Extract which will create a csv file containing all the data. You could transfer the file to a sftp of your choice.
2. Do an initial load "manually" (via UI export data to sftp and download it from there) and just query the delta data regularly with SOAP.